# If Object A is Master and Object B is Detail. OWD for Object A is private. Can you show records of Object B to User X when X is not the system admin?

Tags: administration, master-detail, sharing-rule, owd

I know that for Custom Objects in Master Detail relationship, the OWD for child is 'Controlled by parent'. So here as OWD for Object A is private it means that even records of Object B (child) should not be visible. In this case if we want to share records of Object B to a User (Not System Administrator), do we need to create Sharing Rules for Object A or Object B to share records of Object B?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Maybe lookup?**

The first thing to consider is, that there should be a master-detail relationship? or maybe a lookup will be more relevant? Because you would like to split the sharing of Object A and B, a lookup will match this scenario perfectly.

**Answer**

What is special about Master-detail?

- Detail and subdetail records inherit security settings and permissions from the master record. You can’t set permissions on the detail record independently.
- The owner of the master object record automatically inherits ownership of the detail object records associated with it; ownership cannot be changed.
- **The records in a detail object cannot have any sharing rules exclusively applicable to itself. All sharing rules for a detail record are inherited from its master record.**
- A master record must exist and is required to create and store any detail record.
- Deleting a detail record moves it to the Recycle Bin and leaves the master record intact; deleting a master record also deletes related detail and subdetail records.

**Summary**

Consider using a lookup relationship instead of master-detail. However, if it is not possible, you need to create sharing rules for Object A (so Object B inherits it).

Comment: Yes actually between Object A and Object B it was given Master Detail Relationship. So in that case we need to create Sharing Rule for Object A as per what you said. Is that correct?

Comment: If you cannot change it to lookup without affecting the system, then yes, you need to create Sharing Rule for Object A.